# pgfplots - How to specify default line widths for plots and marker?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I would like to specify different default line widths for plots and for markers (like x-marker). For the plot line width, I use:

```
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={line width=1pt}}
```

Yet, this sets both the line widths of plots and markers. So, either I need an option which only applies to plot lines, or I need to change back the marker line width. Additional marker options are specified locally. Is there something like `every marker/.append options`?

Best Regards!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try the `every mark/.append style` key detailed on Pg. 163 of the pgfplots v1.12 manual? If so, and it didn't work, can you please post a MWE and let us know what went wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `every mark` style; however, due to the way this style is processed, you need to add it to `every axis plot post` to make sure all the keys are evaluated appropriately:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.8pt},
  every axis plot post/.append style={
    every mark/.append style={line width=1.6pt,draw=green,fill=red}
  }
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(-2,0) (-1,1) (0,0) (1,1) (2,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Simply saying

```
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.8pt},
    every mark/.append style={line width=1.6pt,draw=green,fill=red}
}
```

in the above example won't have the desired effect.

An example using `mark=x`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.8pt},
  every axis plot post/.append style={
    mark=x,
    every mark/.append style={line width=1.6pt,draw=red,scale=2}
  }
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(-2,0) (-1,1) (0,0) (1,1) (2,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]